# Web Audio: Recreating an oscillator after timed stop

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I want to sound an oscillator note for 2 seconds.
But the next time, even after recreating a new oscillator, no sound is played:

```
        oscillator = context.createOscillator();

        oscillator.frequency.value = 440;         
        oscillator.type = oscillator.SINE;        

        oscillator.connect(context.destination);          

        oscillator.start(0);
        oscillator.stop(2);
```

If I omit stop(2) and instead use setTimeout() to oscillator.stop() in a function, it works.
I have read that the node should be disconnected, but disconnect() does not accept a time as argument, only an output index. Any pointer for the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "when" parameter to start and stop is based on AudioContext.currentTime.  Zero means "now" - currentTime also starts at zero when the AudioContext is created.  So when you say ".start(0); .stop(2);" the second time around, the "stop" is already in the past (check AudioContext.currentTime - it's already >2), so the start never causes any effect.

Instead of what you're currently doing, do:

```
    oscillator.start(context.currentTime);
    oscillator.stop(context.currentTime+2);
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, now the concept is even clearer to me.